# How to trigger a method every hour irrespective to app active, background or terminated

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nstimer

How to trigger a method for every hour irrespective to application is active or background or terminated.
The method should trigger every hour.

```
   NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60*60 target:self selector:@selector(callYourMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I heard that the NSTimer will not work after 10 min of time.

Can any one advice me how to activate a method that will trigger a method every one hours in iOS Objecitve-C

Comment: There is no sure-fire way of doing this.  Whoever told you timers have a time limit is wrong, or you are missing context.  If an app is terminated, you have to use an external trigger, such as a push kit notification, to launch it again.  Pretty much the same for when it's in the background, but you have more options for waking it up.  None are 100% reliable, though PK gets closest.  Of course your app has to be a VoIP app to use it.

Comment: Do you really need to do something every hour? Because this is a bad design for a mobile app. This way you will drain the battery.  And what if the user kills your app the task is not done. You might better be of doing this server side and push it to you app if needed use a push notification. Also only VOIP, Audio, Location and accessory app can run in the background. Misusing one of these to make you app run in the background will get your app rejected.

Comment: Timer works on Main thread. When application goes into background, its timers become invalid. So, you cant do the same when application goes into background.

Answer (score 0):

Managing this type of task locally is a bad idea. You can't afford to NSTimer or GCD because they're designed to be used when the application is in the foreground state.

When you're in background, the app can invalidate timers or dispatch methods after some minutes and - anyway - at the discretion of iOS. If the system needs to free memory for other apps or optimise the battery consumption, it puts the app in the Suspended state.

You can force the awakening of an app from the Closed or Suspended state only by using VoIP Notifications with the [PushKit Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/PushKit_Framework/), introduced in iOS 8. Note that you should use this type of notifications only in the case you implement VoIP services in you app. This framework is badly documented, first by Apple but also on other sites like StackOverflow. I suggest you to follow [this tutorial by Pierre-Marc Airoldi](http://pierremarcairoldi.com/ios-8-voip-notifications/) that guides you step by step in order to build a fully functional demo of an app that uses VoIP Services.
Note that standard notifications don't do anything when you receive them: the methods in the `AppDelegate` will be fired only if you click on the notification. If you don't want to show the notification to the user, send it without a message; it won't be displayed on screen but it will be received as well.